# Getting Records From Multiple Tables SQL Query With Sum And Abstract Function

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have 5 Tables

```
Table 1 Accounts (as T1)
accountID Title
Table 2 Arrival Master (as T2)
ArrivalID ArrivalDate RefDate PartyID
Table 3 Arrival Details (as T3)
ArrivalID itemid Itemqty ItemRate ItemAmount
Table 4 Return Master (as T4)
ArrivalID ArrivalDate RefDate PartyID
Table 5 Return Details (AS T5)
ArrivalID ItemID Itemqty ItemRate ItemAmount
```

In T2 and T4 ArrivalID is Primary Key.

I want to get summary report in which I have to get these values

```
.
.
.
.
.
t2.ArrivalID
.
t2.ArrivlaDate
.
T2.RefDate
.
T1.Title
.
Amount (Sum of T3.AmountColumn group By Arrival ID)-(Sum of T5.AmountColumn Group By t4.ArrivalID and link to t2.RefDate)
```

Comment: In ArrivalMaster and ReturnMaster [ArrivalId] is differenet. relate them Where RefDate and PartyID is Same.

Comment: can you format your stuff better pls

Comment: https://ibb.co/nggJP5x

Comment: @Perazim An Image Link Attached. New Forum User so dont Know How to Post Pictures Here

Comment: Do you want to use SQL Client, or Entity?  If youi are using SQL Client that get SQL working in query working SQL Server Management Studio before using c#.

Comment: i want to get results in Crystal report of C# Application. I am Using SqlClient Method in C# coding Bcoz i am working on visual Studio 2005 with sql server 2000

Comment: As I said, get query working first with SQL Server Management Studio.  Then query is exactly the same in c#.  The error messages for debugging is 1000% better in SSMS than c#.

Comment: @jdweng i dont know Exact query. i can get results from arrival and Return table with two seperate queries. but i could not get result from two tables in single row.

Comment: to be more clear, an example Here..  i want to get sum of arrival amount grouped by Arrival id. i can do it..... now in second task i want to get sum of return amount grouped by Date. Finaly i want single date return and Arrival amount in single row. and remember that result should in same row if arrival and return Party Title is Same and Ref date of both is Also Same

Comment: https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/9/25/375732d1de354470866256ca0b2d1eb9-full.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication133
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable Accounts = new DataTable();
            Accounts.Columns.Add("Account ID", typeof(int));
            Accounts.Columns.Add("Title", typeof(string));

            Accounts.Rows.Add(new object[] { 225, "Mushtaq" });
            Accounts.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2211, "Akram" });

            DataTable Arrival_Master = new DataTable();
            Arrival_Master.Columns.Add("Arrival ID", typeof(int));
            Arrival_Master.Columns.Add("Adate", typeof(DateTime));
            Arrival_Master.Columns.Add("RefDate", typeof(DateTime));
            Arrival_Master.Columns.Add("Party ID", typeof(int));

            Arrival_Master.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, DateTime.Parse("9/25/2019"), DateTime.Parse("9/25/2019"), 225 });
            Arrival_Master.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, DateTime.Parse("9/26/2019"), DateTime.Parse("9/26/2019"), 2211 });

            DataTable Arrival_Details = new DataTable();
            Arrival_Details.Columns.Add("Arrival ID", typeof(int));
            Arrival_Details.Columns.Add("ItemId", typeof(int));
            Arrival_Details.Columns.Add("ItemQty", typeof(int));
            Arrival_Details.Columns.Add("Amount", typeof(decimal));

            Arrival_Details.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, 1, 15, 500 });
            Arrival_Details.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, 2, 20, 400 });
            Arrival_Details.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, 5, 12, 750 });
            Arrival_Details.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, 7, 15, 150 });
            Arrival_Details.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, 5, 17, 180 });

            DataTable Return_Master = new DataTable();
            Return_Master.Columns.Add("ReturnID", typeof(int));
            Return_Master.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
            Return_Master.Columns.Add("RefDate", typeof(DateTime));
            Return_Master.Columns.Add("Party ID", typeof(int));

            Return_Master.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, DateTime.Parse("9/25/2019"), DateTime.Parse("9/25/2019"), 225 });
            Return_Master.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, DateTime.Parse("9/26/2019"), DateTime.Parse("9/26/2019"), 2211 });

            DataTable Return_Details = new DataTable();
            Return_Details.Columns.Add("RetID", typeof(int));
            Return_Details.Columns.Add("ItemId", typeof(int));
            Return_Details.Columns.Add("ItemQty", typeof(int));
            Return_Details.Columns.Add("Amount", typeof(decimal));

            Return_Details.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, 1, 15, 50 });
            Return_Details.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, 2, 20, 40 });
            Return_Details.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, 7, 15, 90 });
            Return_Details.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, 5, 17, 80 });

            DataTable Summary = new DataTable();
            Summary.Columns.Add("Adate", typeof(DateTime));
            Summary.Columns.Add("RefDate", typeof(DateTime));
            Summary.Columns.Add("ArrivalID", typeof(int));
            Summary.Columns.Add("Title", typeof(string));
            Summary.Columns.Add("ArrivalAmount", typeof(decimal));
            Summary.Columns.Add("Return Amount", typeof(decimal));
            Summary.Columns.Add("Net Amount", typeof(decimal));

            var joins = (from acc in Accounts.AsEnumerable()
                         join am in Arrival_Master.AsEnumerable() on acc.Field<int>("Account ID") equals am.Field<int>("Party ID")
                         join ad in Arrival_Details.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<int>("Arrival ID")) on am.Field<int>("Arrival ID") equals ad.Key
                         join rm in Return_Master.AsEnumerable() on acc.Field<int>("Account ID") equals rm.Field<int>("Party ID")
                         join rd in Return_Details.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<int>("REtID")) on rm.Field<int>("ReturnID") equals rd.Key
                         select new { account = acc, arrivalMaster = am, arrivalDetails = ad, returnMaster = rm, returnDetails = rd }).ToList();

            var groups = joins.GroupBy(x => new { 
                account = x.account.Field<int>("Account ID"), 
                arrivalDate = x.arrivalMaster.Field<DateTime>("Adate"), 
                refDate = x.arrivalMaster.Field<DateTime>("RefDate") }).ToList();


            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                DataRow newRow = Summary.Rows.Add();
                newRow["Adate"] = group.Key.arrivalDate;
                newRow["RefDate"] = group.Key.refDate;
                newRow["ArrivalID"] = group.FirstOrDefault().arrivalMaster.Field<int>("Arrival ID");
                newRow["Title"] = group.FirstOrDefault().account.Field<string>("Title");
                newRow["ArrivalAmount"] = group.Sum(x => x.arrivalDetails.Sum(y => y.Field<decimal>("Amount")));
                newRow["Return Amount"] = group.Sum(x => x.returnDetails.Sum(y => y.Field<decimal>("Amount")));
                newRow["Net Amount"] = group.Sum(x => x.arrivalDetails.Sum(y => y.Field<decimal>("Amount"))) -
                   group.Sum(x => x.returnDetails.Sum(y => y.Field<decimal>("Amount")));
            }

            DataTable newArrivalTable = new DataTable();
            newArrivalTable.Columns.Add("Arrival_Date", typeof(DateTime));
            newArrivalTable.Columns.Add("Arrival_Ref_Date", typeof(DateTime));
            newArrivalTable.Columns.Add("Arrival_ID", typeof(int));
            newArrivalTable.Columns.Add("Party_Title", typeof(string));
            newArrivalTable.Columns.Add("Amount", typeof(decimal));

            var joinArrivals = (from acc in Accounts.AsEnumerable()
                join am in Arrival_Master.AsEnumerable() on acc.Field<int>("Account ID") equals am.Field<int>("Party ID")
                join ad in Arrival_Details.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<int>("Arrival ID")) on am.Field<int>("Arrival ID") equals ad.Key
                select new { account = acc, arrivalMaster = am, arrivalDetails = ad}).ToList();


            foreach (var joinArrival in joinArrivals)
            {
                newArrivalTable.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                    joinArrival.arrivalMaster.Field<DateTime>("Adate"),
                    joinArrival.arrivalMaster.Field<DateTime>("RefDate"),
                    joinArrival.account.Field<int>("Account ID"),
                    joinArrival.account.Field<string>("Title"),
                    joinArrival.arrivalDetails.Sum(x => x.Field<decimal>("Amount"))
                });

            }

            DataTable newReturnTable = new DataTable();
            newReturnTable.Columns.Add("Return_Date", typeof(DateTime));
            newReturnTable.Columns.Add("Return_Ref_Date", typeof(DateTime));
            newReturnTable.Columns.Add("Return_ID", typeof(int));
            newReturnTable.Columns.Add("Party_Title", typeof(string));
            newReturnTable.Columns.Add("Return_Amount", typeof(decimal));


            var joinReturns = (from acc in Accounts.AsEnumerable()
                         join rm in Return_Master.AsEnumerable() on acc.Field<int>("Account ID") equals rm.Field<int>("Party ID")
                         join rd in Return_Details.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<int>("REtID")) on rm.Field<int>("ReturnID") equals rd.Key
                         select new { account = acc, returnMaster = rm, returnDetails = rd }).ToList();


            foreach (var joinReturn in joinReturns)
            {
                newReturnTable.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                    joinReturn.returnMaster.Field<DateTime>("Date"),
                    joinReturn.returnMaster.Field<DateTime>("RefDate"),
                    joinReturn.account.Field<int>("Account ID"),
                    joinReturn.account.Field<string>("Title"),
                    joinReturn.returnDetails.Sum(x => x.Field<decimal>("Amount"))
                });

            }

            var combinedJoins = (from at in newArrivalTable.AsEnumerable()
                                join rt in newReturnTable.AsEnumerable() on at.Field<int>("Arrival_ID") equals rt.Field<int>("Return_ID")
                                where at.Field<DateTime>("Arrival_Ref_Date") == rt.Field<DateTime>("Return_Ref_Date")
                                select new { arrivals = at, returns = rt }).ToList();

            DataTable combinedTable = new DataTable();
            combinedTable.Columns.Add("Arrival_ID", typeof(int));
            combinedTable.Columns.Add("Party_Title", typeof(string));
            combinedTable.Columns.Add("Arrival_Date", typeof(DateTime));
            combinedTable.Columns.Add("Arrival_Ref_Date", typeof(DateTime));
            combinedTable.Columns.Add("Amount", typeof(decimal));
            combinedTable.Columns.Add("Return_Date", typeof(DateTime));
            combinedTable.Columns.Add("Return_Ref_Date", typeof(DateTime));
            combinedTable.Columns.Add("Return_ID", typeof(int));
            combinedTable.Columns.Add("Return_Amount", typeof(decimal));

            foreach (var combinedJoin in combinedJoins)
            {
                combinedTable.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                    combinedJoin.arrivals.Field<int>("Arrival_Id"),
                    combinedJoin.arrivals.Field<string>("Party_Title"),
                    combinedJoin.arrivals.Field<DateTime>("Arrival_Date"),
                    combinedJoin.arrivals.Field<DateTime>("Arrival_Ref_Date"),
                    combinedJoin.arrivals.Field<decimal>("Amount"),
                    combinedJoin.returns.Field<DateTime>("Return_Date"),
                    combinedJoin.returns.Field<DateTime>("Return_Ref_Date"),
                    combinedJoin.returns.Field<int>("Return_ID"),
                    combinedJoin.returns.Field<decimal>("Return_Amount")
                });

            }



        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello. Thanx But this code is in C# Application. I Have To get asked data from sql database. So I Need Sql query which can help me to get data id data table or datatable adapter

Comment: Exactly.  My code is after you put results into table.  I put your test data manually into table because I did have a database.  Once you use the adapter to fill data then you use my code.  The query to database should be select * from table (replace with table name).

Comment: You need 5 queries.  One for each table where the query string is "select * from [Arrival Master]" (or you can specify the columns instead of the asterisk).  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: if I Use Two Seperate queries to get result of Arrivals And Return Summaries. I got My Desire Results. Now I Have To Combine These Results.

Comment: For Example. In Result 1 Igot Arrival_Date,Arrival_Ref_Date, Arrival_ID,PArty_Title, & Arrival_Amount. In Result 2 I got Return_Date, Return_Ref_date, Return_Id, Party_Title, Return_Amount. Now I ahve to Combine these two result based on Ref_date and party_Title. Return_ID is Not Compulsory in Third Result.

Comment: Seriously I can't Under stand Your Joining and also Other Variable used in this code. I am wiling to Exact SQL Query. Which i Can Use in Stored Procedure.

Comment: You can use a DataAdapter to fill a DataTable.  I assumed you knew how to extract the data from the SQL Server and just had issues with the joins.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Hello jdweng, i have issue in extracting data from Sql. Your Code Uses joins but it is also New Tech for me as i am new in c# Coding

Comment: The joins are the Net Linq library.  See : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b